# Getting error -cannot find type 'PLMediaTitles' in scope

Tags: ios, swift

I am running a project, here PLMediaTitles is a class and I am trying to set it to a property as

```
let playListAlbum = RecommendedCategoryArray[indexPath.row] as? PLMediaTitles
```

but I am getting error like -

> "Cannot find type 'PLMediaTitles' in scope".
> what can be the solution?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to import the module PLMediaTitles resides in? Instead of just asking what the solution could be you should provide info on what this class is and what you have tried yourself to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have imported That PLMediaTitles, but still getting error - " No such module 'PLMediaTitles' ". kindly help. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Kindly help with what? There is not enough information here to help you much further but please read again what I wrote about importing, import the module (library/framework) the class belongs to, not the class itself.

Comment: I have imported module, but got the error  - "this module may not be available in this context." @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Check App Settings>Build phase > Compile source and check the file is exists or not .

Comment: okay @FaysalAhmed